# Make copy of online Power BI report which is Embedded in .net

Tags: rest, .net, powerbi

I have One online Power BI Report , And our team embedded the report in .net via html5 and knockout ,angular js.

My client wants a button through which on clicking it a Copy of that report get's created.

May I know how can I do this ,And what's the best approach( REST API's,JSON )

Comment: you need to copy its embedded code of power BI and append any where using jquery i.e., add iframe contain embedded code using jquery.

Comment: Please go through the request please .